# Ropsten Node finally synchronized after 3 days: why a blockchain testnet should be so difficult?

Tags: testnets, ropsten

I have started a new Ropsten Node running on a Pi4 4GB.

Here is the relevant information for those who might want to start a new Ropsten Node:

- more than 3 day syncing
- $ geth --ropsten --datadir /mnt/ropsten --cache 2048
- SSD 250GB mounted on /mnt/ropsten, connected through Pi4's USB3.0 (tested speeds read/write > 350MB/250MB), for all Ropsten Node's files
- $ df -hT => 85GB disk space used
- **"Imported new state entries" processed** = 263.974.548 (29Oct2020) this is the **most important** number to watch for (to know how close your Node is to be in sync)... ;-)
- "Imported new state entries" pending = 0 finally...
- on console > eth.syncing yields "false" => in sync ;-)
- eth.currentBlock => 8.975.055

Now my question is: why should it be so difficult to start a **TEST**net blockchain?
Is it really necessary to be so difficult (time consuming)?